# Ordering query result by list of values

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a sql query that is passed a list of values as a parameter, like

```
select * 
from ProductGroups
where GroupID in (24,12,7,14,65)
```

This list is constructed of relations used througout the database, and must be kept in this order.

I would like to order the results by this list. I only need the first result, but it could be the one with GroupId 7 in this case.

I can't query like

```
order by (24,12,7,14,65).indexOf(GroupId)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Additional info:**
Building a join works and running it in the mssql query editor, but...

Due to limitiations of the software sending the query to mssql, I have to pass it to some internal query builder as 1 parameter, thus "24,12,7,14,65". And I don't know upfront how many numbers there will be in this list, could be 2, could be 20.

Comment: Could you have the parameter passed in as xml and then you could grab the values dynamically?

Comment: The problem with this list of values is that it is used in various location in my app. I can make small changes to it before passing it as parameter, like changing the ',' to '</value><value>'.
The dev tool (WebDev12) uses some kind of string replacement to build the queries, so {Parameter} will be replaced with a value I provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a table variable or temporary table with an identity column, feed in your values and join to that, e.g.

```
declare @rank table (
    ordering int identity(1,1)
    , number int    
    )

insert into @rank values (24)
insert into @rank values (12)
insert into @rank values (7)
insert into @rank values (14)
insert into @rank values (65)

select  pg.*
from    ProductGroups pg
left outer join 
    @rank r
on  pg.GroupId = r.number 
order by 
    r.ordering
```

Comment: Great! Just to make life easier, from SQL Server 2018, you can do: INSERT INTO @rank(number) VALUES (24), (12), (7), (14), (65). This way you save a bit of INSERTs and manage better for a bigger list of values ;)

Answer (score 14):

You can also order by on a CASE:

```
select * 
from ProductGroups
where GroupID in (24,12,7,14,65)
order by case GroupId 
    when 7 then 1 -- First in ordering
    when 14 then 2 -- Second
    else 3
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I think I might have found a possible solution (but it's ugly):

```
select * 
from ProductGroups
where GroupID in (24,12,7,14,65)
order by charindex(
             ','+cast(GroupID as varchar)+',' ,
             ','+'24,12,7,14,65'+',')
```

this will order the rows by the position they occur in the list. And I can pass the string like I need too.

Comment: seems like this would me a performance hog compared to using a temp table.  breaking a delimited string isn't hard, there's lots of code on the net to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm no sql expert, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Just the answer I'm looking for - requires the least work to implement a list of unknown values and of unknown size

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly for ordering small dynamic lists without the hops of temps, joins and cases. well done!

Answer (score 2):

Do a join with a temporary table, in which you have the values that you want to filter by as rows. Add a column to it that has the order that you want as the second column, and sort by it.