# Order query result by list of IDs passed as argument

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a function returning a list of objects which ID is within a given array:

```
public static List<T> findByIds(int[] ids) {        
    final String where = "_ID IN (" + StringUtils.implode(ids, ",") + ")";
    final Cursor c = db.query(TABLE, ALL_COLUMNS, where, null, null, null, null);

    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(c.getCount());
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        final T t = createFromCursor(c);
        result.add(t);
    }
    c.close();

    return result;
}
```

I need the result to be in the same order as the `ids` function parameter. At most the `ids` function parameter will be having 200 to 300 elements.

I had a look at [Ordering query result by list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831799/ordering-query-result-by-list-of-values) which seems to address the same kind of issue but there is a lot of SQLServer specific stuff in the answers.

Any suggestion for a solution based either on SQL (to get the result ordered) or Java (order the result afterwards) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always manually sort the results yourself, if the list is short enough: build a map, based on the sort order as the key, then build a new list based on the sort order. It's not *efficient*, I'd say, but efficiency is less important than running code. Here's an example:

```
package sorting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SortResult {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] sortOrder = { 5, 2, 8, 4, 14, 1, 6, 9, 3, 7 };
    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        thing.setId(i);
        things.add(thing);
    }
    Map<Integer, Thing> thingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Thing>();
    for (Thing thing : things) {
        thingMap.put(thing.getId(), thing);
    }
    List<Thing> sortedThings = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    for (int id : sortOrder) {
        if (thingMap.get(id) != null) {
            sortedThings.add(thingMap.get(id));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("expected order: "+Arrays.toString(sortOrder)
                 +"\nActual order: ");
    for(Thing thing:sortedThings) {
        System.out.println(thing);
    }
}
}

class Thing {
int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Thing [id=").append(id).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: That's what I'll use until I have some time (and the need) to optimize that function. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
java.util.Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Pass your ids to the Comparator and use the position of the it of a T to do the ordering.

Comment: As my ID array is not sorted, I think this would be less efficient than some lookups in a HashMap even if it is more efficient memory-wise. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.