# SQL Server Select query with IN() and order by the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a `SELECT` query with an `IN` clause, as well as `Order by`:

```
select * 
from table 
where column_id IN (5,64,2,8,7,1)
```

This code returns `1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 64`.

Now I need to return the same select in order

Output needs to be:  `5, 64, 2, 8, 7, 1`

In Mysql, field option is there, but SQL Server does not have such a field option.

Comment: Your question is unclear what you want to achieve. Please provide more details

Comment: You want the result to appear in the same order as the IN list. How is the IN list generated? from a list? There is no simple answer to this. You need to actually load the in list into a table with an additional order by column.

Comment: I have to **select * from table where column_id IN (5,64,2,8,7,1)** 
it return default column_id Asc. Now need to change the Order of listing.

Comment: Can you post a reference to the MySQL option you're talking about? To order the results from a table you need an `ORDER BY`. So what field are you going to order by? Where does the in list come from? Do you type it in? There is no native way to do what you want.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Your Correct Need to order by select IN list

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185029/sort-by-order-of-values-in-a-select-statement-in-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: OK. There's no similar function in SQL Server. @DVT answer or a variation on that is what you need to do. That's why I asked where the in list came from - because you need to put some smarts in

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831799/ordering-query-result-by-list-of-values

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/396748/253096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL-Server, when you want to order by something, you have to specifically spell it out.

Try this

```
select * from table where column_id IN (5,64,2,8,7,1)
order by
case column_id
    when 5 then 1
    when 64 then 2
    when 2 then 3
    when 8 then 4
    when 7 then 5
    when 1 then 6
    else 10
end;
```

Comment: (5,64,2,8,7,1) This values comes dynamically. VB.net program

Comment: Comes dynamically in what order?

Comment: This Query Worked Me. Thanks for @DVT and Nir Kornfeld

Answer (score 11):

Use the values you want to search in a **[`Table Valued Constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)** and also give a row number and then join it with your table and then order it according to the values in the table valued constructor.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM(VALUES(1, 5), (2, 64), (3, 2), (4, 8), (5, 7), (6, 1)) t2([rn], [id])
JOIN [your_table_name] t1
ON t1.[id] = t2.[id]
ORDER BY t2.[rn];
```

Also you can create a table variable with the values you want to search and also an identity column in that. And then join it with your table.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE([rn] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [id] INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl([id]) VALUES(5), (64), (2), (8), (7), (1);

SELECT t1.*
FROM [your_table_name] t1
JOIN @tbl t2
ON t1.[id] = t2.[id]
ORDER BY t2.[rn];
```

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Sorry, my mistake. I have updated my answer,

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit complicated, but you can do this:

```
WITH inner_tbl (key, orderId) AS
( 
SELECT key, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SELECT 1)
FROM (VALUES (5),(64),(2),(8),(7),(1) ) d
)
SELECT table.* FROM table 
INNER JOIN inner_tbl ON table.column_id=inner_tbl.key
ORDER BY inner_tbl.orderId
```

The ROW_NUMBER function will create the order column you need.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed. Why not just add the OrderId to the values clause explicitly rather than relying on a non deterministic row number that can be optimised out.

Comment: Of course adding the order will be more absolute, but will also complicate the query. From my tests, row_number() over(order by select 1) will keep the order

Comment: There's a difference between "happening in your tests" ( which just shows it works at least some of the time) and "being documented as guaranteed to always happen"

Answer (score 0):

First, create a string split function in your sqlserver:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn_split](@text NVARCHAR(2000), @delimiter NCHAR(1))
    RETURNS @retable TABLE([s_key] NVARCHAR(64))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index INT;
    SET @index = -1;
    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text);
        IF (@index > 1)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @retable VALUES(LEFT(@text, @index - 1));
                SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index));
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @retable VALUES(@text);
                BREAK;
            END
    END
    RETURN;
END
```

Second, using sql query like this:

```
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(200)='5,64,2,8,7,1';
SELECT * FROM [table] a INNER JOIN (SELECT [s_key] FROM [fn_split](@ids, ',')) b ON [b].[s_key] = a.[column_id];
```