# Order by data as per supplied Id in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [MemberBackup].[dbo].[OriginalBackup]
where ration_card_id in
(
1247881,174772,
808454,2326154
)
```

Right now the data is ordered by the auto id or whatever clause I'm passing in order by.

But I want the data to come in sequential format as per id's I have passed

**Expected Output:**

```
All Data for 1247881
All Data for 174772
All Data for 808454
All Data for 2326154
```

**Note:**
Number of Id's to be passed will 300 000

Comment: Read the 3 Lac+ IDs into a table, or temporary table, and then go from there.

Comment: but the insertion on the temp table will not be in the given format right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Select query with IN() and order by the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712032/sql-server-select-query-with-in-and-order-by-the-same)

Comment: @Ullas yes i think it's quite similar but the data i need to pass is more

Comment: It's doesn't depend on volume of data, you can get the output in the same way as low volume data. So my suggestion is to follow the link above.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a CTE containing the `ration_card_id` values and the orders which you are imposing, and the join to this table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1247881 AS ration_card_id, 1 AS position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 174772, 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 808454, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2326154, 4
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM [MemberBackup].[dbo].[OriginalBackup] t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.ration_card_id = t2.ration_card_id
ORDER BY t2.position DESC
```

**Edit:**

If you have many IDs, then neither the answer above nor the answer given using a `CASE` expression will suffice.  In this case, your best bet would be to load the list of IDs into a table, containing an auto increment ID column.  Then, each number would be labelled with a position as its record is being loaded into your database.  After this, you can join as I have done above.

Comment: what if the number of id's i have to pass is more?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Then can consider creating a formal table and using it.

Comment: thanks for replying can you please explain how?
AS if i will try to insert data into new table then also the order is not in the same manner

Answer (score 0):

If the desired order does not reflect a sequential ordering of some preexisting data, you will have to specify the ordering yourself. One way to do this is with a case statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MemberBackup].[dbo].[OriginalBackup]
where ration_card_id in
(
1247881,174772,
808454,2326154
)
ORDER BY CASE ration_card_id
    WHEN 1247881 THEN 0
    WHEN 174772 THEN 1
    WHEN 808454 THEN 2
    WHEN 2326154 THEN 3
END
```

Stating the obvious but note that this ordering most likely is not represented by any indexes, and will therefore not be indexed.

Comment: what if the number of id's i have to pass is more?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Then you should try to identify a reason for the ordering rather than arbitrarily ordering by some external sequence of ids. Or if the sequence is external, add them to a table with an index first.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your ration_card_id's in #temp table with one identity column.
Re-write your sql query as:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM [MemberBackup].[dbo].[OriginalBackup] a
JOIN #temps b
on a.ration_card_id = b.ration_card_id
order by b.id
```